# How do i replace a character with another character in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I need to replace all `I`'s in a variable `%ps%` with `1`'s and send the output to another variable `%ps2%`

Comment: `set "ps2=%ps:I=1%"`

Comment: is there any way to multiple changes like I=1 and a=2?

Answer (score 0):

as single replacements, just a simple:

```
set "ps2=%ps:I=1%"
```

for multiple replacements either specify new lines for each or you could run a `for` loop, but you'll need to define the search replace items regardless:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "ps=Iab"
set "search_rep="I=1","a=2","b=4""
if not defined ps2 set "ps2=%ps%"
for %%i in (%search_rep%) do set "ps2=!ps2:%%~i!"
echo %ps2%
```

Take note of the use of `delayedepansion` in the above example.